# Mouse leave after editing div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

When I hover over `#hoverme`, I want `#header` to change the height. But I also want it to go back to normal, once the mouse has left `#hoverme`.

Does anyone know how to do this? My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kench3bL/) doesn't seem to work as intended.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hoverme').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('#header').css('height', '500px');
  });

  $('#header').on('mouseout', function(){ 
    $('#header').css('height', '100px');
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="hoverme">hover over me</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```js
#header { 
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Where is `#hoverme` coming from? You don't mention it in your question.  Also, why are you doing this with JavaScript?  I feel that you could accomplish this with pure CSS.

Comment: Make sure your referring to the correct Elements, then use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead, to avoid bubbling issues.

Comment: Second the CSS - `#header:hover{ height:500px; }` - but if you want a jQuery one-liner: `$('#header').hover(function(){$(this).height(500);},function(){$(this).height(100);});`

Comment: @zero298 i had it in the jsfiddle but i updated the question

Comment: Ah... change mouseout to mouseleave - like @itsgoingdown 's answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `mouseout` use `#hoverme` as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hoverme').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('#header').css('height', '500px');
  });

  $('#hoverme').on('mouseout', function(){ 
    $('#header').css('height', '100px');
  });
});
```

and change the `div` of `hoverme` to a `span` so that not the entire line is used:

```
  <span id="hoverme">
    hover over me
  </span>
```

The new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yrhdxdf/)

Comment: I don't want it to change on #header, I want it to change on `#hoverme` hover.

Comment: Ok, let me see.. you should change your question then!

Comment: @bryan I edited my answer. Hope it works for you now!

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the first sentence in your question to: "When I hover over #hoverme, I want #header to change the height. But I also want it to go back to normal, once the mouse has left #hoverme." It is now in peer review. I believe that is what you intended to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "work as intended", but try this:

```
$(function(){

var hdr = $('#header');
hdr.mouseenter(function(){
  hdr.css('height', '500px');
});
hdr.mouseleave(function(){ 
  hdr.css('height', '100px');
});

});
```